# REQUEST_DENIED response using Google Places Autocomplete API

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api, google-places-api

I am working on android app which uses google's places autocomplete API.

When tried to hit following URL

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Vict&types=geocode&sensor=false&language=en&key=apiKey

I got the response as below.

{
    "predictions" : [],
    "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}

I got the API key from link below
[Google APIs console](http://code.google.com/apis/console)

also i have enabled Google Maps API v3 service.
As per API documentation REQUEST_DENIED response is generally due to lack of sensor parameter but which i have already provided.
After hitting above URL directly in browser also i am getting REQUEST_DENIED response.
Is anything else i have to do?

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure your key is correct and that you have enough quota left? Try generating a new key and checking that you have the referrals correct/set to empty.

You also may need to wait up to 5 minutes for the key to become active.

FWIW I tested your URL with my own key and it worked fine.

Comment: I don't know whether key is wrong.but i have followed Google APIs console steps.also enabled Google Maps API v3 service.Tried generating new API key without any referrals.The Simple API Access shows                                                             Key for browser apps (with referers)
API key: 
xyz(sample)
Referers: 
Any referer allowed
Activated on: Feb 5, 2012 10:01 PM
Activated by:  vmjadhav.31@gmail.com – you
Obsolete key: 
xyz(sample)
Status: 
Active until Feb 6, 2012 10:01 PM

Comment: You should create a Places API service instead of the Google Maps V3 service if you want to use the Places API. You will need to generate a key for that specific service too.

Comment: skarE can i have your personal mail id?

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the same issue "REQUEST_DENIED" when using google places API for my android app. As per Google API console help "Android and iOS keys are only supported by some APIs, such as the Google Maps Android API or the Google Maps SDK for iOS." (https://developers.google.com/console/help/).

In my case problem solved by using the 'key for bowser apps' instead of using android/iOs keys.

Comment: Did you pay for it? Am using browser and am getting this error `This Api project is not authorized to use this api. Please ensure that this api is activated in the APIs console....` My question is how do I activate? I have not seen anywhere to activate, I have enabled google places api

Answer (score 0):

I dont see **input** parameter listed on API page http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/#PlaceSearches

What does it do? If you really need to have it, try moving it to the last item. Or just try removing it first to see if it works.

Comment: Actually my question is regarding places auto complete request(http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/autocomplete.html#place_autocomplete_requests) for which input is mandatory parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you are facing is may be related to API_KEY.You inserted something like
letter "l" instead of capital "i". Capital i and el(l) looks same in the xcode 
 environment.Try to insert correct letter will solve the issue.